# windows server 2008 backup re-import schedule after reinstall

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup

I originally had a windows 2008 server with software mirrored volumes and a backup volume.
The backup volume was a dedicated drive and hidden by the windows backup software feature of windows 2008 server. Ok, here's the deal, I reinstalled windows 2008 server on new hardware, took the disks and plugged them in after the os installation. The software raid volumes we imported and are working. The hidden backup volume was automatically detected by windows and assigned a drive letter, all without my doing anything. What I would like to do I re-establish the backup schedule and re-hide the volume as it was before. I am at a loss of how to go about doing this, it lets me browse my backups but I would like to put everything back how it was before. If I create a new schedule and select use dedicated drive it says it will delete all the old data, which I don't really want to do. Ideas?

Comment: How are you doing the backup?  Windows Server Backup doesn't hide the drive that I am aware of.  It simply creates a backup image on the drive as needed.  If you are using the schedule, it should just backup to the drive as a backup image.  Maybe your setup was somehow tweaked, but that doesn't sound like a vanilla Windows Backup setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore your backup catalog from your old disk and then continue to store backups to it using the command "wbadmin restore catalog" but you will have to setup the schedule again manually.